# How to calculate RSA MD5 signature in separate steps?

Tags: java, rsa, md5, signature

I use the following 2 steps to calculate the signature, why is it different
Use java code

```
1-  Signature s1 = Signature.getInstance("MD5withRSA");
// some code
String b1 = base64Encode(doFinalData);

2-  byte[] md5 = MD5.md5("data content");
byte[] rsa = RSA.rsa(md5);
String b2 = base64Encode(rsa);

// Why b1 and b2 are not equal
```

Is my understanding wrong, or the code is wrong

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: If you're thinking about implementing your own RSA algorithm, you might want to reconsider. Take a look at https://robertheaton.com/2013/07/29/padding-oracle-attack/ , an interesting read on how bad padding implementation compromised the entire implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure which library you are using for #2, but it looks like raw RSA encryption.

When you perform `"MD5withRSA"` in #1 you'll actually use [PKCS#1 v1.5 padding for signature generation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-8.2.1). This will create a structure that specifies the MD5 algorithm and the MD5 signature value. Then it will pad that, and finally it will perform the modular exponentiation with the private key. The steps are described in detail in the standard.

However, if #2 is just raw RSA then it will simply convert the MD5 to a positive integer and use that as input for modular exponentiation. So the padding and structure before the MD5 hash is missing.

---

Just a small additional note: the signature scheme using PKCS#1 v1.5 and raw RSA are deterministic. This is not a property that is present for all schemes: RSA-PSS or ECDSA will always generate different signature values. So to test if a signature is valid, you'll have to perform the signature verification using the public key rather than a binary compare.